# MySQL: How to design a Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ingredients / meals table setup, where X ingredient combinations can equal Y meals.

For example: 
`Ingredients` 'Carrots, Meat, Cabbage' = `Meal` Stew.

The user will get to select and add their own ingredients, which will then produce a meal. I have made both of these tables a many2many relationship. I realized I needed a 3rd table for adding ingredients PER meal, but the problem I ran into is cost.

For example:
Lets say you wanted to make a sandwich meal. You would add bread (1$), meat (1$) and some cheese (2$). This would make the meal "sandwiches" 4$.

The problem I am running into, is my MEAL table has a "cost" column, and my meal-ingredients linked to meal have a "cost" column, but the MEAL must be created first, and then ingredients SELECTED, which means it doesn't KNOW the total cost yet, because the ingredients come last.

How can I tell mysql that the TOTAL COST of the meal is the ingredients that are yet to be put in?

Comment: Couldn't you get rid of the `meals.cost` column altogether and compute it dynamically by summing the cost of the list of ingredients?

Comment: It's not exactly fine dining though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit how you're entering the data, but let's assume you have an interface for `meals` and an interface for `meal-ingredients` (presumably written in PHP since you tagged this as such).

What I would do is, when you update or create an ingredient, that you either use a trigger that would update `meals.cost` OR have your PHP script run that query after an insert/update. That way your `cost` should always be accurate. In the case of the field, I would make it have a default of `0` (a meal with no ingredients technically has no cost)